# Share OAuth config between multiple connected apps?

Tags: oauth, canvas, connected-apps

I'm building an application that consists of several independent "Canvas" components, all of which are different views into the same application.

At the moment it appears I'm required to configure a separate "Connected App" for every instance, each with their own independent OAuth configurations - despite the fact that they are all, effectively, the same app.

Apart from the obvious codebase overhead of having to deal with multiple oauth profiles, this requires the user manually approve each individual component instead of just being able to approve the whole application once.

Is there any way to share OAuth credentials across multiple connected apps or canvas components?

Answer (score 0):

you use the option 'Admin approved users are pre-authorized' for Permitted user under OAuth Policies. This allows admins to pre-approve users based on profiles and permission set and would not require users to manually approve the connected app.